# printing tensors in tensor flow version > 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to `keras` and `tensorflow`.
Running the code below in google colab prints the following:

```
TF Version:  2.2.0
Keras Version:  2.3.1
'float32' # the type of tf.keras.backend.dtype(loss)
```

I am interested in printing the values of `layer_output`, `loss`. `Tensor flow` versions above `2.0` don't need a `session`.
But I still run into errors in printing `layer_output`, `loss`...any ideas would be helpful in how to print the actual values contained in these tensors

```
import keras
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf


print("TF Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Keras Version: ",keras.__version__)

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
              include_top=False)

layer_name = 'block3_conv1'
filter_index = 0

layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
tf.keras.backend.dtype(layer_output)
loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])
tf.keras.backend.dtype(loss)
# tf.print(loss)
```

Comment: The output of a layer or a model only makes sense when we feed the model some input data.

Comment: Thanks, understood. This is a pre-trained model on `imagenet` and we are only looking at the very first layer. Would this not have all activations from this layer? Would `layer_output` be empty until we use the `filter_index` (Source see ln[12] at: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

To print the activations of the intermediate layer, you will have to pass in an input image, this can be conveniently done using `keras.backend.function`

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet',
              include_top=False)

layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
fn = tf.keras.backend.function(model.input, layer_output)
random_image = tf.random.uniform([1, 224, 224, 3])

output = fn(random_image)
print(output.shape)
```

output:

```
(1, 56, 56, 256)
```

But if you just want to check what's actually stored the layers, you could just printing the convolution filter weights, and here is how you can it

```
layer_name = 'block3_conv1'
filter_index = 0
conv_filters = model.get_layer(layer_name).kernel
loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(conv_filters[:, :, :, filter_index])
print(loss)
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(-0.0004023569, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```